# Where to put scraper script in django so as to access django database

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, web-scraping

I have a script which populates a database with initial data(football matches) from a web scraper..Currently I have put it under init.py but looks and sounds wrong..Here is my code in init.py..Where should I put this code so that it updates the matches field in my database?..Kindly help

```
 from .models import Betting

import re
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urls= "https://sms.betyetu.co.ke/tomorrow.html"
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "html.parser")


for i in soup.findAll("table"):








    try:
        momo = 1
        a = len( i.contents[3].contents)
        while momo <= a:


       foo = Betting(matches=i.contents[3].contents[momo].findAll("td")[2].text)

        momo += 2


        **strong text** foo.save()




 print i.contents[3].contents[3].findAll("td")[0].text
except:
    momo = 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't set up a urls and views structure so that you can run the code at will by accessing a certain URL and/or performing a button action? Putting this script somewhere in your startup sequence means it will run every time you run the web app. It may run more than once. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Micheal....My general goal is to setup a cronjob to update my Django ORM..what I dont know is where to put the code to do this..

Comment: a cron job relies more on your server than Django itself. You may want to look into how to specify a cron job on your server. For example on google app engine you can create a cron.yaml file which points to any script file you wish to be executed at a certain interval. Django doesn't touch this. There are some scheduling modules out there that may do what you need. I have heard one for Python called APScheduler which could perhaps handle your request in pure Python code. Take a look and see what you find.

Comment: Ok..thanks..will look into that